# Remove work profile from personal device

Tags: samsung, work-profiles

According https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/6191949?hl=en:

> 1. Go to Settings > Accounts > Remove work profile.
> 2. Tap Delete to confirm the removal of all apps and data within your work profile.
> 3. Ensure that the policy app ("Device Policy") is uninstalled and not present on your device.

My Samsung Galaxy S10 with Android 11 doesn't have Settings > Accounts. The closest I can find is Settings > Accounts and backup > Manage accounts. But then when I click on the Work profile, select an account, and click Remove account. I get "This change isn't allowed by your admin." What do I need to do to remove the Work profile from my personal phone?

Comment: How did you setup work profile originally? If you used a third-party app such as Island to create work profile, then you would need to use that app to remove work profile, or at least remove it first as an administrator and then try deleting the work profile. You can also try running the command `adb shell pm remove-user USER_ID` where `USER_ID` is the user id of the work profile user. You can find the USER_ID of work profile user using the command `adb shell pm list users`.

Comment: And if the Work Profile is added by your office, you cannot remove it. Ask them to remove the account, if they allow.

Comment: @Firelord IIRC, I added my google work account directly in settings and was asked if I wanted to create a work profile. I didn't use any third-party app for this.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I added the work profile myself to my personal device.

Comment: I found this (but I haven't tried it): Settings > Work profile > Uninstall Work profile.

Comment: @Joe That's more or less what I tried. The exact wording for the options in Android 11 is shown in my question along with the error that it gave.

Answer (score 3):

The option you are looking for is "uninstall work profile", not "remove account". If you use the search bar in your settings menu then it should come up.

I just did it and it worked perfectly. I had the same problem as you do. I will try to add a screenshot to demonstrate.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the answer here. What device and version of Android is this?

Comment: Samsung note 10+ running android 12

Comment: It requires a pin code to uninstall, but I don't have it. Why would anyone put an UNinstall behind a pin code?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up contacting my previous employer. They had to remove the profile on their end via the administrative UI.

Comment: Update: I just tried the "Settings > Work profile > Uninstall Work profile" option and it worked perfectly. I did not need to contact my previous employer.

Comment: @Joe As I said in my question, I get an error message when I did that.

Answer (score 1):

Probably irrelevant to the original question based on newer OS version, but thought I'd mention it for reference. On Samsung S7 running Android 8, I had to go into the Workspace (app) section, for the workspace created for that work profile, and uninstall the workspace from the workspace app settings. Only then was I also able to remove the MDM app that set up the workspace. There was no workspace settings with the Settings app.